# Issues with camera sensor in ML agents

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, deep-learning, ml-agent

I am trying to make an AI using ML agents but I can't seem to get the camera sensor to actually give input. I have followed several tutorials but none of them go in depth enough for what I want and if they do they are very outdated. Here is my code:

```
    using UnityEngine;
    using Unity.MLAgents;
    using Unity.MLAgents.Sensors;
    using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
    using Unity.MLAgents.Actuators;

    public class MyAgent : Agent
    {
    Rigidbody2D rb2D;
    public bool space;
    public Vector3 targetPos;
    [SerializeField] CameraSensor Observer;
    public void Start()
    {
        rb2D = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        Observer = GetComponent<CameraSensor>();
    }
    public override void OnActionReceived(ActionBuffers actions)
    {
        if (actions.DiscreteActions[1] == 1)
        {
            space = true;
            RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, new Vector2((float)0.1, 1), 100000.0f, 1);
            targetPos = hit.point;
        }
        else
        {
            space = false;
        }
    }
    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.tag == "Obstacles")
        {
            AddReward(-50f);
            EndEpisode();
            SceneManager.LoadScene(0);
        }
        else if (collision.tag == "Checkpoint")
        {
            AddReward(1f);
        }
    }
    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (space == true)
        {
            if (targetPos.x > transform.position.x && rb2D.velocity.x < 20)
            {
                rb2D.velocity = new Vector2(rb2D.velocity.x + (0.05f * (20 - rb2D.velocity.x)), rb2D.velocity.y);
            }
            else if (rb2D.velocity.x < -20)
            {
                rb2D.velocity = new Vector2(rb2D.velocity.x - (0.015f * (20 - rb2D.velocity.x)), rb2D.velocity.y);
            }
            if (targetPos.y > transform.position.y && rb2D.velocity.y < 20)
            {
                rb2D.velocity = new Vector2(rb2D.velocity.x, rb2D.velocity.y + (0.025f * (20 - rb2D.velocity.y)));
            }
            else if (rb2D.velocity.y < -20)
            {
                rb2D.velocity = new Vector2(rb2D.velocity.x, rb2D.velocity.y - (0.025f * (20 - rb2D.velocity.y)));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the error I'm getting:

> ArgumentException: GetComponent requires that the requested component
> 'CameraSensor' derives from MonoBehaviour or Component or is an
> interface
>
> Fewer observations (0) made than vector observation size (1). The
> observations will be padded. UnityEngine.Debug:LogWarningFormat
> (string,object[]) Unity.MLAgents.Sensors.VectorSensor:Write
> (Unity.MLAgents.Sensors.ObservationWriter) (at
> Library/PackageCache/com.unity.ml-agents@2.0.1/Runtime/Sensors/VectorSensor.cs:56)

I'm not sure if this is caused by something I'm missing in my code or if it's a component I'm missing or something like that.

Comment: See last answer at following posting : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68013135/how-to-getcomponent-from-other-gameobject

Comment: There was another error I was getting and I added it to the original post. Thank you for responding.

Comment: Need line where error is occurring and exact error message.

Comment: the error is: Fewer observations (0) made than vector observation size (1). The observations will be padded.
UnityEngine.Debug:LogWarningFormat (string,object[])
Unity.MLAgents.Sensors.VectorSensor:Write (Unity.MLAgents.Sensors.ObservationWriter) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.ml-agents@2.0.1/Runtime/Sensors/VectorSensor.cs:56)

Comment: You are not getting any data back in response or the response is in a different format than what code needs.  At top of my link it says "This question already has been answered".  The is a link to another posting which has tons of debug information.